# Get the id of selected tag using the instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, web

Hi I have a scenerio such that i've many td tags with same class name but different id .I need to get the id value when onclick on the tab.For example this is my html tag

### my Html tag

```
<td class="sameClassName" id="1"></td>
<td class="sameClassName" id="2"></td>
<td class="sameClassName" id="3"></td>
```

now on clicking in the class i have to get the corresponding id.I tried something like this

```
$(".sameClassName").click(function(){
 alert($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

But i dont get the required result.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you get anything? Does clicking the first one work?

Comment: code looks perfect, Are you seeing any errors on consloe.?

Comment: This code should work. Do you see anything on console?

Comment: I dont get anything.Not even error message

Comment: Check if your HTML document has jquery loaded. I doubt that.

Comment: If you have invalid table structure then events wont get fired like this http://jsfiddle.net/Q8h9m/1/ ,Post your html structure for that table..

Comment: If you have valid HTML then your code works correctly. See http://jsfiddle.net/cNG9G/

Answer (score 0):

use this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankchaturvedi/h5b93/)

```
$('.sameClassName').click(function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
  e.stopPropagation()
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Insure that your event handler defined AFTER all your html code OR in the `$().ready` event.

There are four different ways to get an ID of an element:

```
$(".sameClassName").click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

or

```
$(".sameClassName").click(function(){
    alert($(this).get(0).id);
});
```

or

```
$(".sameClassName").click(function(){
    alert($(this).prop('id'));
});
```

or

```
$(".sameClassName").click(function(){
    alert(this.attributes.id.value);
});
```

Here is example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25PRf/